# Node JS - Mongoose - How to properly join the results from two collections by ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following Schemas for tracking Habits, and a user's progress

HABIT SCHEMA

```
const HabitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["Goal", "Limit"],
    default: "Goal",
    required: true,
  },
  dateStarted: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

PROGRESS SCHEMA: each time a user clicks that they completed a habit for a given period (day, week, month etc) a document will be created for that period, to indicate that it was done.

```
const ProgressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  habit: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Habit",
  },
  period: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    required: true,
  },
  value: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

When I get all of a user's habits, I want to also get all progress documents per habit. I want to join these objects before returning.

Here's what I have attempted:

```
let habits = await Habit.find({ user: req.user.id }).sort({
  dateStarted: -1,
});

habits = await Promise.all(
  habits.map(async (h, i) => {
    try {
      const progress = await Progress.find({ habit: h._id });

      return { ...h, progress };
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  })
);
res.json({ habits });
```

This gives the error: `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Habit"`

What would be the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: what is `i` there. Also, `req.user.id` is not ObjectId type, hence the error. So you need to turn that req.user.id into ObjectId type, right?

Comment: `i` is just the index of the item in `habits` provided to the callback function by `.map()`. I should have clarified, the req.user.id is not causing the ObjectId related error,it is working fine. The `Progress.find({ habit: h._id })` is what is causing the error.

Comment: That error doesn't seem to fit the code.  It sounds like it's trying to convert the `_id` field of an object passed to the `Habit` model constructor to an `ObjectId`.  I don't see that happening in the snippet provided.  Are you sure it's happening on the line you suspect (it can be a little confusing with the async code breaking the stack trace)?

Comment: Why not use `$lookup` to fetch both habit and progress in single query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't understand why the error came up considering that I used await/async so the line should not have been running before an id was retrieved (the error was saying ._id is undefined when it clearly wasn't).

After trying lots of things, here is what finally worked:

```
try {
  await Promise.all(
    habits.map(async (h, i) => {
      let progress = await Progress.find({ habit: h._id });
      let newHabit = h;
      newHabit._doc.progresses = progress;
      return newHabit;
    })
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).send("Server Error");
}
```

Once I finally got the `await Progress.find({ habit: h._id });` to work, I also found out that I can't just add to a mongoose retrieved object with a spread operator. The object has many properties, and the fields from the database are actually contained within the ._doc property of the object: `newHabit._doc.progresses = progress` (but this has nothing to do with the error I was getting). This makes me think there is a better way for adding fields to a document found by mongoose `.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to use [.lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) since you're not running any function like .save so you don't need the additional items that the find query returns.

```
let habits = await Habit.find({ user: req.user.id }).sort({
  dateStarted: -1,
}).lean();

habits = await Promise.all(
  habits.map(async (h, i) => {
    try {
      const progress = await Progress.find({ habit: h._id }).lean();

      return { ...h, progress };
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
  })
);
res.json({ habits });
```

And still better solution would be to use [ref and populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `lean()`, edited my code. For populate I would need to have the ids for the progress docs in the habit doc, rather than each progress object holding the habit id, correct?

Comment: You can use aggregate as well if you don't want to change your schema your code will continue to be good to go till you reach some good amount of data in your DB so you can continue with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Mongoose, however, in vanilla MongoDB you can use the aggregation framework like so to do this:

```mongodb
db.Habbit.aggregate([
  { $lookup: {
    from: "Progress",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "habbit",
    as: "Progresses"
  } }
])
```

Yet more, you can add a step to discard all but the latest progress instead of returning them all. However, I'll leave this for another question.